# C++: char test[100] vs array<char, 100> vs string

Tags: c++

If I have a string that I know will be of constant length, what should I use?

```
char test[100]
std::array<char, 100> test
std::string test
```

Thanks!

Comment: `std::string`, which offers the interface of a ... string

Comment: depends on what you want to do with it

Answer (score 8):

The answer is in the question:

> If I have a **string** ...

If you have a string, use `std::string`. Unless you have very specific requirements that you have not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ a string should be declared as a `string` instance. But if you need it to be constant then declare it as a `const string` and initialize it properly.

`char test[100]` is not a string but a C-array of 100 chars (that can be used to build a C++ string if needed).

`std::array<char,100> test` is just a C++ array of hundred chars, nothing related to string.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you know it will be constant length or not, it's pretty much always going to be recommended that you use `std::string`. Having the string be contained in an actual string object enables you to query the string for metainformation (length, for example) and integrate better with C++ functionality for handling strings. If ensuring that the string /cannot/ be more than 100 characters is super vital to you, you might find

```
std::array<char, 100>
```

to be valuable, but I can't think of any situations where you'd rather have that functionality than just using a string.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason otherwise you should prefer a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  Not only does this say that the data is a string but you get all of the nice string functions as well.

You also get the benefit that if you decide to change the code and allow variable/larger sized strings then you don' need to change anything as `std::string` will scale